# Docker compose file ownership

Tags: django, docker-compose, file-ownership

I created Django project with Docker Compose:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /code/example
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "manage.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
postgres:
  image: postgres
  ports:
  - '5432:5432'

django-project:
  build: .
  command: runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
  - .:/code
  ports:
  - '8000:8000'
  links:
  - postgres
```

It work nice.
But all new files which create through container 'django-project' have root owner and group.

I try add `user: user` in Compose config for container `django-project`.
But got exception `User user not found`.

I try add `user` in container with code:

```
ENV HOME_USER user
ENV HOME_PASS password

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash ${HOME_USER} && \
    echo "${HOME_USER}:${HOME_PASS}"|chpasswd && \
    adduser ${HOME_USER} sudo && \
    echo ${HOME_USER}' ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

But exception stayed.

How I can apply non-root ownership for all new files which will create through docker container?

Comment: You need to create a new user in your dockerfile that will be assigned ownership, then chown the /app folder to that user.

Comment: I add user with code as in question, but new file still create with root as owner. I make `docker-compose up` from non-root user. Can I set this user as owner for all new files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `useradd` worked then the last piece of the puzzle is to switch to that user in the Dockerfile to run particular commands when the container is built:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

Note that specifying `user: user` in the docker-compose.yml only affects the final process that's run when you start the container (i.e. the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`)
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user

So you need to:

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV HOME_USER user
ENV HOME_PASS password

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash ${HOME_USER} && \
    echo "${HOME_USER}:${HOME_PASS}"|chpasswd && \
    adduser ${HOME_USER} sudo && \
    echo ${HOME_USER}' ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

USER user

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /code/example
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "manage.py"]
```

Alternatively you could run everything as `root` user but `chown` all the files as a `RUN` step in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV HOME_USER user
ENV HOME_PASS password

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash ${HOME_USER} && \
    echo "${HOME_USER}:${HOME_PASS}"|chpasswd && \
    adduser ${HOME_USER} sudo && \
    echo ${HOME_USER}' ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/

RUN chown -R user /code

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /code/example
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "manage.py"]
```

Comment: I tryed both of your recipies, but the didn't help. When I create new migrations with command `docker-compose run django-project makemigrations example` new migration's files have root as owner.

Comment: that's something different again... try looking at the docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/ ...run with `-u` flag

Comment: I tried with my host username and username of created in container user. Got error "Unable to find user..." in both cases.

Comment: you need to both create the user when building the image, with `RUN useradd` in the dockerfile, and also `docker-compose run -u <user from dockerfile>`

Comment: Yes. When I wrote I had tried username from container I meant what I builded it in container. This case didn't help me. I got error 'Unable to find user user'

Comment: then it sounds like your `user` user did not get created properly... try `run`ning a bash shell in the image you built and find out what has happened

Comment: thank for true way - watch logs. Needed add user and used him for `ENTRYPOINT`. `MKDIR` didn't work with him: said "Permission denied"