# Why is docker-compose creating files with a root owner and how can I modify the docker-compose.yml file to stop it?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am building a Django app to run using Docker.

In the docker-compose.yml file, I am using volumes to save changes.

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

When I create a new application within the Django project, I use...

```
docker-compose exec web python manage.py startapp app_name
```

Docker-compose writes the app (app_name) to my local file, as expected, but with a root owner. This is causing problems, because, if I want to then create a new file within the app, I don't have permission.

If I exit docker-compose and create the app as a user, then there are no issues.

How can I change the .yml file to fix this?

Comment: Found answer here ... [composer file ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008744/docker-compose-file-ownership)

Comment: Can you use a non-Docker Python virtual environment instead?  That will similarly isolate your application's library stack from the rest of the system, but it will run directly using your development tree as your host user.